# elasticsearch term aggregation query returns no results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elastic search v6.5 with an index of 300 million documents.
Documents field type keyword, example `{"url": "http:/linkedin.com/435"}`.

```
   {  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "duplicateCount":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"url",
            "min_doc_count":2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I got 0 results, then posted `test_url` value 2 times to the URL again, launched the query and it remains an empty set. What is the reason and is
there any way to overcome the issue?

Comment: There is no query clause and only aggregation. Can you post the complete query? Please add more clarification to your question.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant For aggregation, no query clause required

Answer (score 0):

```
  {  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "duplicateCount":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"url.keyword",
            "min_doc_count":2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You need to add **.keyword** at the end of field name.
Try this. Hope this will work.

Comment: This won't work unless you have a keyword field within the test field (using fields option)